# Trouble with POST API using cURL

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I'm trying to post to an API using cURL with no luck. I've been researching this for 2-days now and I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is an example of a URL that I can paste into a web browser and it works, no problem:

```
http://{myserver}:{port}/api.aspx?Action=AddTicket&Key=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&Subject=Test&Description=Test&Username={domain}\{username}
```

(I obviously redacted some information).

I know that cURL is up to date and working on the server because I can make a simple request out to [**http://www.google.com**] and it returns the page properly and I've also confirmed it on the php.info page as being **ENABLED**.

I've tried every layout I can find for the cURL code such as settings the **POSTFIELDS** as an array as well as a string. I've followed along with multiple YouTube videos and web tutorials to the 'T' with no success. I've even tried setting the URL parameter in the *$ch* to the entire above URL just for the heck of it... No success.

Can anyone explain or give examples of how this should be formatted so that it simply posts a URL identical to the one above??

Much appreciated!

As requested, here's my code.

```
$url = 'http://{server}:{port}/api.aspx?Action=AddTicket';
$post_data = '&key=' . $key . '&subject=' . $subject . '&description=' . $details . '&username={domain}\{username}';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output === false) {
        echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

And here is my attempt using an array instead of a string for the POSTFIELDS.

```
$url = 'http://{server}:{port}/api.aspx?Action=AddTicket';
$post_data = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'description' => $details,
        'username' => '{domain}\{username}'
    );
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output === false) {
        echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

### EDIT

I've tried some of the examples given in the comments. Here's a small test I'm currently running.

```
$data = array(
        'Action' => 'AddTicket',
        'Key' => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Subject' => 'test',
        'Description' => 'test',
        'Username' => '{domain}\{username}'
     );

$query = http_build_query($data);

$url = 'http://{server}:{port}/api.aspx?' . $query;

print_r($url);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Now, if I straight up take the $url variable from the above code and run this...

```
header("Location:" . $url);
die();
```

It works perfectly... so my problem has to be something in the cURL syntax or parameters...

### EDIT

After adding the following code...

```
var_dump($resp);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
var_dump(curl_error($curl));
```

I get the following result...

```
string(0) "" 
int(401) 
string(0) ""
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: how'bout showing your php code instead of this lengthy verbiage ?

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code"

Comment: Also, including information about the error you're getting (e.g. from `curl_error()`) would be helpful. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on what information to include in your past. Also, when you say you've tested it with the Google URL, do you mean you tested your code with that URL, or you tested command-line curl with it?

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, the general format example you've provided uses GET parameters, not POST.  If the system is expecting POST but you are sending GET, that may be the problem right there.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I don't get any errors. Just a blank page. I've gotten errors before when I had accidental white-space or other things, but no errors currently.

Comment: Examining the output you get from `curl_exec` ought to reveal what's happening now.  You're issuing a successful request, but the server is returning some kind of status or login page that would explain why the ticket isn't being added.  Most likely because the auth isn't being done correctly.

Comment: How would I examine that? I've tried to print_r and echo the result but it's always blank.

Comment: `var_dump($resp); var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)); var_dump(curl_error($curl));` should hopefully yield something.

Comment: var_dump($resp) - returns string(0) ""
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) - returns int(401)
var_dump(curl_error($curl)) - returns string(0) ""

Comment: The 401 status means not authorized, so whatever API key or auth that is required is not working.  You'll need to figure out if this is HTTP Basic Auth, a cookie/session based login, or NTLM auth and get it working with curl as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, but I just can't figure this out. I've tried all the authentication options on the cURL handle but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone suggest a different method to call to an URL based API that won't display the URL in the address bar??

Comment: Maybe just git rid of the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` option altogether?  In it's current form, it's not being used right and isn't working so that might be getting in the way.

Comment: I've tried many, many combinations (including without the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH) with no success.

Comment: The 401 error is the server saying the request is "Not Authorized".  Either due to the API key being set incorrectly, or some other cookie or form of authentication missing that you have set when you test in your browser.  Unfortunately without knowing any more about what type of system you are talking to or what it's expecting, there's not much more we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Seeing your latest update, try using json_encode on your postfields.

The URL you're supplying uses GET parameters. Hopefully the below snippet should help;

```
    $curl = curl_init();


    // Heres our POSTFIELDS
    $params = array(
        'param1'  => 'blah1',
        'param2'  => 'blah2'
    );

    $params_json = json_encode($params);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params_json
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that did not work for me. I tried adapting it to my current code and also just copy and pasting your code and adjusting the details. No luck, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your working example indicates that this is not a POST request at all, but instead a GET request.

Try building your URL like so:

```
$data = array(
    'Action' => 'AddTicket',
    'key' => $key,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'description' => $details,
    'username' => '{domain}\{username}'
);

$query = http_build_query($data);

$url = 'http://{myserver}:{port}/api.aspx?' . $query;
```

Then you probably only need to perform a GET request to that URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not having any luck. I've tried a straight HTTP_GET() request as well as a GET request using cURL and still nothing happens...

Comment: Do you have to log in to be able to AddTicket?  Most likely auth is the problem now.

Comment: No, you don't have to log in.